Visualising $\dot{\theta} = r - 3$
I am trying to visualise a sketch in $\mathbb{R^2}$ of:
$\dot{\theta}= r - 3$ (with respect to time)
So we get that Θ is constant for r = 3. So what does this mean, visually?
Thank you

What is $\dot\theta$?  More precisely, if $\dot\theta := \frac{d\theta}{d\square}$ what is the $\square$?

Echoing @BrianMoehring 's sentiment -- does $\dot{\theta}$ mean $d\theta/dt$? Or $d\theta/dr$? Or what? If it's $t$, then are $\theta$ and $r$ both dependent on $t$?

It’s with respect to time @BrianMoehring


So what does this mean, visually?

Wherever the curve passes through a point that has $r$ value $3$, it passes through that point radially. Meaning the tangent line to the curve there is a line from the origin through that point.
Note we can just make up a particular solution to your equation $(r(t),\theta(t))=(2t,t^2-3t)$ and see this phenomenon:

In the comments, it is suggested that maybe $\dot\theta$ means $\frac{d\theta}{dr}$. But even then it's the same story. And we can also make up some solution like $\theta=\frac12r^2-3r$ and see the same feature:


So to clarify the tangent line is the line via the origin that’s tangent to the curve at r = 3?

Yes, in both plots the green curve is a solution to the differential equation. The circle/arc lets you see the place where that curve crosses $r=3$. The tangent line is drawn there, and you can see that it is a radial line.
